# Enabling caching resulting 500 error in DXA 2.0 Java and RedHat Linux server

Tags: dxa, web8.5, dxa-java, dxa-2.0, cache

We are using SDL Web 8.5 with DXA 2.0 and Java. The java application is deployed on Red Hat Linux server  using Java version "1.8.0_161" 64 bit and Tomcat 8.5.30 .We are getting 500 server error when DXA caching is enabled but if we disable the DXA Caching using

```
spring.profiles.active=dxa.no-cache
```

website loading fine

we are getting below 500 server error when caching is enabled

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.sdl.dxa.caching.TridionCacheConfiguration.lambda$null$4(TridionCacheConfiguration.java:53)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$11$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:372)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Collections$2.tryAdvance(Collections.java:4717)
    at java.util.Collections$2.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:4725)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
    at com.sdl.dxa.caching.TridionCacheConfiguration.lambda$cacheResolver$5(TridionCacheConfiguration.java:54)
    at org.springframework.cache.jcache.interceptor.AbstractCacheInterceptor.resolveCache(AbstractCacheInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.cache.jcache.interceptor.CacheResultInterceptor.invoke(CacheResultInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.cache.jcache.interceptor.JCacheAspectSupport.execute(JCacheAspectSupport.java:131)
    at org.springframework.cache.jcache.interceptor.JCacheAspectSupport.execute(JCacheAspectSupport.java:102)
    at org.springframework.cache.jcache.interceptor.JCacheInterceptor.invoke(JCacheInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
    at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.modelservice.ModelServiceClient$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$dee1a1aa.getForType(<generated>)
    at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.modelservice.DefaultModelService._loadPage(DefaultModelService.java:56)
    at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.modelservice.DefaultModelService.loadPageModel(DefaultModelService.java:37)
    at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.impl.DefaultContentProvider._loadPage(DefaultContentProvider.java:100)
    at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.impl.DefaultContentProvider.getPageModel(DefaultContentProvider.java:175)
    at com.sdl.webapp.common.controller.PageController.getPageModel(PageController.java:290)
    at com.sdl.webapp.common.controller.PageController.handleGetPage(PageController.java:119)
    at com.sdl.dxa.modules.generic.controller.GenericPageController.handleGetPage(GenericPageController.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.tridion.ambientdata.web.AbstractAmbientDataServletFilter.doFilter(AbstractAmbientDataServletFilter.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Update

ehcache.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns="http://www.ehcache.org/v3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.ehcache.org/v3 http://www.ehcache.org/schema/ehcache-core-3.1.xsd">
    <cache-template name="default">
        <expiry>
            <ttl unit="seconds">5</ttl>
        </expiry>
        <resources>
            <heap unit="entries">10000</heap>
        </resources>
    </cache-template>

    <cache alias="defaultCache" uses-template="default" />
</config>
```

Comment: TGe error points to an invalid caching configuration. So check your settings. Maybe something as simple as a missed xml closing tag. For best answers though, update your question with the config.

Comment: @NickoliRoussakov i have checked XML file it is properly closing all tags

Comment: In the dxa.properties file dxa.caching.required.caches=?? what is the value?

Comment: @Velmurugan it is dxa.caching.required.caches=defaultCache,failures

Answer (score 2):

So, according to the Stack Trace, there is a `NullPointerException` at line 53 in [TridionCacheConfiguration.java](https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-java/blob/release/2.0/dxa-framework/dxa-tridion-common/src/main/java/com/sdl/dxa/caching/TridionCacheConfiguration.java).

Good luck with post-mortem analysis. :-)

See: https://community.sdl.com/product-groups/sdl-tridion-dx/tridion-sites/b/blog-posts/posts/digital-forensics-based-on-a-stack-trace

**UPDATE**

There are three things on line 53 that could cause a `NullPointerException`:

1. The result of the previous line, i.e. the result of the `map` method
2. The `log` object
3. The `cache` parameter of the lambda expression

Looking at the first line of the Stack Trace, the exception occurred in a lambda expression. So, it’s either #2 or #3.

Comment: Rick after looking at the code it seems issue is code is not able to get cache name and when it is trying to get cache using  cacheManager().getCache(name) system is throwing null pointer expression.

Comment: You mean that `cacheManager().getCache(name)` returned `null`, so that the `cache` lambda parameter on line 53 becomes `null` resulting in a `NullPointerException`  on `cache.getName()`?  I would agree that seems to be the most likely cause.

Comment: Rick what could be the root cause ?

Comment: I have to tell you a little secret: I don’t know _everything_. I’m just trying to help out with the analysis.